# Как получить родителя в сессии SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
class Project(DataBase):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    domain = Column(String, nullable=False)
    phrases = relationship("Phrase", backref='proj')

    def __init__(self, name, domain):
        self.name = name
        self.domain = domain


class Phrase(DataBase):
    __tablename__ = 'phrases'

    query_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    query_text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    project = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id'), nullable=False)
    enable = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)


    def __init__(self, query_text, project, city):
        self.query_text = query_text
        self.project = project
```

Есть функция получения одного объекта из таблицы 2 (дочерней):

```
def get_first_query():
    session = Session(bind=engine)
    q = session.query(Phrase).filter(Phrase.enable == True).first()
    session.close()

    return q
```

Я хочу получить объект из таблицы 2, а затем по нему получить объект из таблицы 1 (получить его родителя):

```
session = Session(bind=engine) 
q = get_first_query()
print(q.proj)
```

Такой код не работает и выдает следующую ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance  is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of
>   attribute 'proj' cannot proceed

Понятно, что я могу решить свою задачу так:

```
session = Session(bind=engine) 
q = get_first_query()
q_project = session.query(Project).filter(Project.id == q.project)
```

Но зачем тогда вообще нужна связь в данном случае? Что-то тут не так.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя каким либо образом взаимодействовать с объектами сессии после её закрытия(Её вообще надо только 1 раз на весь сеанс работы открывать). 
Так что, только так:

```
def get_first_query(session):
    return session.query(Phrase).filter(Phrase.enable).first()


session = Session(bind=engine)

print(get_first_query(session).proj)

session.close()
```

P.S: Также у вас неправильные __init__ методы...

Comment: Суть проблемы я понял. Немного не так как вы написали, но починил. А что не так с init?